# Как вывести результат работы функции в переменную, которую я собираюсь использовать вне этой функции?

Tags: javascript, jquery

я хочу, чтобы другая функция (или несколько функций) использовали результат работы первой функции `move`, то есть показывали, чему в данный момент равна переменная `w`.

Вот пример:

```js
function move() {
  var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth
}
$(window).resize(move);


$('.button').click(function() {
  alert(w);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Узнать ширину</div>
```

в примере не срабатывает функция по клику, так как переменная `w` не найдена

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если по простому, используйте глобальную область видимости:

```
var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth; // первая инициализация
function move() {
    w = document.documentElement.clientWidth
}
$(window).resize(move);


$('.button').click(function() {
    alert(w);
})
```

А еще можно так:

```
function move() {
    move.w = document.documentElement.clientWidth
}
$(window).resize(move);


$('.button').click(function() {
    alert(move.w);
})
```

Хотя от предыдущего примера почти не отличается ничего, ф-ция `move` все равно должна быть видна в области видимости обработчика `click`

Comment: в первом варианте как я понял, в переменную w занесется ширина документа, при изменении размеров окна сработает функция, которая вычислит эту ширину повторно, но по клику, в alert все равно ведь попадет ширина которая вычислилась изначально  до изменения (ширины окна) или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, чуть ошибаетесь, в нашем случае `w` - глобальная переменная, если мы в ф-ции обращаем к ней, без ключевого слова `var`, то работаем с глобальной, поэтому присваивая ей значение,изменится наша глобальная `w`. Ваш пример не работал, потому что вы создавали свою локальную `w`, которая не видна снаружи ф-ции `move` - отсюда и ошибки

Comment: что-то начинаю понимать, код мой существенно сократится теперь, а то понагородил оберток))

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, почитай про `область видимости` в `javascript`, это очень крутая штука