# Как вывести результат работы функции в переменную, которую я собираюсь использовать вне этой функции для отображения в html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Доброго времени суток. К сожалению я только новенький в программировании и много не понимаю, но буду очень благодарен за помощь. Такая ситуация. Есть калькулятор стоимости товара, которые по введенным значения выдает стоимость услуги. Нужно прикрепить к страницам простую корзину. Такую нашел которая мне подходит, только вот не могу сделать так, чтобы я рассчитал стоимость услуги(она считается корректно) и вывести ее в корзину.
Вот два скрипта

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('.hidden_field').parent().hide();

            $('#get_result').click(function(){

                var sure_field_count = 0;

                $('.sure_field').each(function(){       
                    if( $(this).val() == '' ) sure_field_count++;           
                });

                if( sure_field_count == 0 ){
                    eval(" result_proc =parseFloat($('#id_2 option:selected').val())*parseFloat($('#id_1 input').val())");
                    if( isNaN(result_proc) ) $('#view_result').html('Поля заполнены неверно!');
                    else $('#view_result').html(result_proc.toFixed(1));    
                }               
                else $('#view_result').html('Не заполнены обязательные поля!');
            });


    $(function(){
        'use strict';   
        // инициализация плагина
        $.jqCart({
                buttons: '.add_item',
                handler: './php/handler.php',
                cartLabel: '.label-place',
                visibleLabel: true,
                openByAdding: false,
                currency: '&euro;'
        }); 
        // Пример с дополнительными методами
        $('#open').click(function(){
            $.jqCart('openCart'); // открыть корзину
        });
        $('#clear').click(function(){
            $.jqCart('clearCart'); // очистить корзину
        }); 
    });
    });
```

Вот html калькулятора

```
<div id='result_calc_page' style='width:890px;min-height:30px;background:#F7F7F7;border:3px dashed #cccccc;padding:20px;'>
        <p class="sortable" id="id_2" style=""><select>
        <option value="30000">Шкаф без стекла 30000 п.м.</option>
        <option value="36000">Шкаф со стеклом 36000 п.м.</option></select>
        <input type="select" style="display:none;"></p>
        <p class="sortable" id="id_1">Погонных метров: <span class="sure_field_char">*</span><br>
        <input class="sure_field" placeholder="" type="input" value="0"></p>
        </div>
        <br><h3></h3>
        <button id='get_result'>Рассчитать</button>
```

Вот кнопки отправки в корзину товаров

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="label-place"></div><!-- Элемент, где будет расположен ярлык корзины -->
  <br>
  <div class="item_box">
    <img src="img/samsung.png" alt="">
    <h3 class="item_title">Шкаф</h3>
    <p>Цена: <span class="item_price"><p id='view_result'></p></span></p>
    <button class="add_item" data-id="1" data-title="Wkaf" data-price="result_proc" data-img="wkaf.png" >Добавить в корзину</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item_box">
    <img src="img/lg.png" alt="">
    <h3 class="item_title">LG Optimus G E100500</h3>
    <p>Цена: <span class="item_price">0.6</span>$</p>
    <button class="add_item" data-id="2" data-title="LG Optimus G E100500" data-price="0.6" data-img="http://incode.pro/demo/icp_example20/img/lg.png">Добавить в корзину</button>
  </div>

</div>
<p>
  <button id="clear">Очистить корзину (вызов метода clearCart)</button>
  <button id="open">Открыть корзину (вызов метода openCart)</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести результат работы функции в переменную, которую я собираюсь использовать вне этой функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505961/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%

Comment: Да я видел этот вопрос. побывал. Но ничего не работает. И как я понял причина в моих руках :(

Answer (score 1):

Я с Jquery не дружу. Вот набросал Вам пример на нативном JS, как получить результат работы функции, за ее пределами. Может так станет понятней.

```
function getRezult (arg1, arg2){
    var rezult = arg1+arg2;
    return rezult;
}
// результат работы функции попадет в переменную
var b = getRezult(1,2);
console.log(b);
```