# Как менять значения переменных при обработке событий из другого класса javascript?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Есть класс с обработчиком, который вычисляет направление – InputManager.

Как в главном классе Game менять значения переменныx при каждой обработке события в InputManager?

На [codepen](https://codepen.io/zemil/pen/jYOmeM?editors=0010) или:

```
class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.size = 4;
    this.score = 0;

    this.inputManager = new InputManager;
  }

}

class InputManager {
  constructor() {
    this.mouseDown_position = {};
    this.events = {};
    this.listen();
  }

  listen() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
      this.mouseDown_position = {
        x : event.clientX,
        y : event.clientY
      };
    });

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
      let mouseUp_position = {
        x : event.clientX,
        y : event.clientY
      };
      let deltaX = this.mouseDown_position.x - mouseUp_position.x,
          deltaY = this.mouseDown_position.y - mouseUp_position.y;

      // MOVE DIRECTION:
      // LEFT
      if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY) && deltaX > 0) {
        console.log('left');
        return 'left';
      }
      // RIGHT
      if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY) && deltaX < 0) {
        console.log('right');
        return 'right';
      }
      // UP
      if (Math.abs(deltaY) > Math.abs(deltaX) && deltaY > 0) {
        console.log('up');
        return 'up';
      }
      // DOWN
      if (Math.abs(deltaY) > Math.abs(deltaX) && deltaY < 0) {
        console.log('down');
        return 'down';
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: Результат работы InputManager передать в переменную, и значения в Game присваивать этой переменной

Comment: можно пример, вроде так и делаю, но не работает как надо..

Comment: Так покажите, как Вы делаете и у Вас не получается. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756557/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2 Здесь в ответе можете посмотреть, что я имею ввиду

Comment: @Дмытрык, вот поправил https://codepen.io/zemil/pen/jYOmeM?editors=0011, в консоли можно видеть направления движения мышью, если бы работало, то направление в консоли дублировалось бы

Comment: У Вас все работает, но неправильно или ошибку выкидывает? Если ошибку, то укажите ее. И вот эта строчка `this.listen();` точно так пишется? Может `this.listen = listen();`?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо передать контекст Game для манипулирования его содержимым(в том числе вызов функции) из другой функции/класса.

```js
class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.size = 4;
    this.score = 10;
    this.inputManager = new InputManager(this);
    this.direction = this.inputManager.direction;
    console.log(this.direction);
  }
}

class InputManager {
  constructor(gC) {
    console.log(gC.score);
    this.gC = gC;
    this.mouseDown_position = {};
    this.events = {};
    this.direction = null;
    this.listen();
  }

  listen() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
      this.mouseDown_position = {
        x : event.clientX,
        y : event.clientY
      };
    });

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => { 
    
      this.gC.score++;
      console.log(this.gC.score);
      
      let mouseUp_position = {
        x : event.clientX,
        y : event.clientY
      };
      let deltaX = this.mouseDown_position.x - mouseUp_position.x,
          deltaY = this.mouseDown_position.y - mouseUp_position.y;

      // MOVE DIRECTION:
      // LEFT
      if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY) && deltaX > 0) {
        console.log('left');
        this.direction = 'left';
      }
      // RIGHT
      if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY) && deltaX < 0) {
        console.log('right');
        this.direction = 'right';
      }
      // UP
      if (Math.abs(deltaY) > Math.abs(deltaX) && deltaY > 0) {
        console.log('up');
        this.direction = 'up';
      }
      // DOWN
      if (Math.abs(deltaY) > Math.abs(deltaX) && deltaY < 0) {
        console.log('down');
        this.direction = 'down';
      }
    });

  }
}

var game = new Game();
```